# Display Results by group/batch using php

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file

I'm creating an application wherein the results would display in a group/batch

Sample Output Should be:
Batch 1:
Display->All Entity From DB
Batch 2:
Display->All Entity From DB
Batch 3:
Display->All Entity From DB

```
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT *,sum(counter) FROM table_name GROUP BY batch") or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());

    if(!empty($qry))
    {           
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                    {


                            for($b=1;$b<=$row['sum(counter)'];$b++){
                                echo $b;
                            }   
                        }
                        echo "<hr>";    


                        echo "<div><input type='submit' name='submitBtn' value='submit'></div>";

    }else{
        echo "No data"; 
    }

?>
```

I was able to get the number[s] of registered users but the problem is on my while loop(I think)..
The result I am getting is
Batch 1:
1,2(Correct)
Batch 2:
1(should be 3)
Batch 3:
1,2(should be 4,5)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that each time you loop through you reset your $b = 1

Comment: Is the SQL statement the actual statement or just a sample? The current statement does not return a usefull result set for your actual task...

Comment: Hi Laurence Burke, I just used it to initialized the variable.

Comment: Hi ZombieHuner, it's just a sample query... but basically that's how my query works.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {
                        for($b=1;$b<=$row['sum(counter)'];$b++){
```

---

In your loop, you are constantly resetting $b = 1.

Try defining $b=1 before the while loop.

Comment: Hi Kurt Funai, I tried your suggestion but now the only result I am getting is Batch1:1,2 Batch2:(Gone)Batch3:(Gone)

Comment: You are echoing the value of $b, not the value you are looking for.

"Batch 1: 1,2(Correct) Batch 2: 1(should be 3) Batch 3: 1,2(should be 4,5)"

$b is constantly being reset to 1, so it is echoing as 1, 2 (loop ran twice). Are you looking for a specific value to be displayed?

If you just want a count to display the total values, you could have a separate value called $total, defined before the while loop, that would increment inside the for loop, and then echo'd

Comment: I am trying to displayed the IDs but the problem is the $b is resetting to 1 so I can't fetch the IDs properly

Comment: Did some quick googling to see if someone is handling this similarily, found this: [link](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php) Hope it helps

Comment: If you could provide a var_dump() on the results, I might be able to help a little more.

Comment: Hi Kurt Funai.. Thanks for the link, it gave me some ideas.. I managed to solve the problem, what I am doing is wrong.. what I did was, query all batch put it to temp_var create another sub query for all the vars that needed to be displayed..

Comment: @bockie Glad to hear that you could fix the issue, sorry I wasn't more help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop doesn't make sense. It simply counts from 1 to the number retrieved from `sum(counter)`. What you want is the actual users, so you need to get their IDs or whatever from your result. Also I strongly recommend using an alias for the `sum(counter)` column.

Comment: Hi ZombieHunter.. I tried to retrieved the IDs of the users but the problem is the $b is resetting to 1, so I can't get the IDs..

Comment: @bockie: Please post your original SQL statement. I think it is wrong for what you want to do.

Comment: Hi ZombieHunter.. The problem is solved.. What I did was I query all the batch put it to a temp_var create a sub query for the other variables that need to be displayed.

Comment: @bockie: this can easily be done using a single query. I recommend you get rid of the GROUP BY clause and use a ORDER BY instead. This way you get the actual values with one SQL statement.